# bad access in a simple multi-thread programm on MAC OS X Yosemite

Tags: multithreading, macos, memory, crash, imagemagick

ImageMagick lib crashes when convert large image (more than 1Mb) in a separate thread.
My simple test program crashes too with the same message:

```
#include <thread>
void foo() 
{
    const int size = 0x7FCC9; //program crashes when size is equal or more than this value
    char buff[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        buff[i] = i;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo(); //passed!
    std::thread thr(foo);
    thr.join(); //got error :(
    return 0;
}
```

i == 58736 :)

> Thread2: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address = 0x103512000)

Why my simple code produces this error?
How i can increase memory size for thread on MAC OS?

Comment: What has this code got to do with ImageMagick? It doesn't include any ImageMagick headers or call any ImageMagick functions.

Comment: that's right. If start ImageMagick in separate thread it crashes when ImageMagick read all from large file. My simple program create buffer and iterate them, like we read and convert large file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack size in main thread more then in child thread, so in main thread your buffer stay inside stack size, but in child buffer pass outside and you got Thread2: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address = 0x103512000)

I suggest you use boost threads:

```
boost::thread::attributes attrs;
attrs.set_size(4096*10);
boost::thread myThread(attrs, fooFunction, 42);
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.attributes